# Could you help me with my loop calculator?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop, char

I am making a calculator for school project. My problem is, that when I input e.g. `1` at `op = sc.next().charAt(0);`, the first `if` statement does its body, even if it's not true. Also, it doesn't return at the start of the loop, but the program ends. I'm  still new at Java so that's why I'm here.
Also, I am open to any suggestions to make it better. :)

Thank you!

````
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Kalkulacka {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Vitajte v programe na výpočet jednoduchých matematických príkladov!");
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        double a;
        char op = 0;
        double b;
        double priklad = 0;
        int i=0;
        System.out.println("Zadajte číslo");

        a= sc.nextDouble();

        priklad= a;



        while (true) {

            if (i<1) {
                System.out.println("Zvoľte si operátora:");
                System.out.println("1- +");
                System.out.println("2- -");
                System.out.println("3- *");
                System.out.println("4- /");

                op = sc.next().charAt(0);

                if (op != 1 && op != 2 && op != 3 && op != 4) {
                    System.out.println("Zadali ste nesprávne číslo");
                    return;
                }
            }

            if (i>=1) {
                System.out.println("Zvoľte si operátora:");
                System.out.println("1- +");
                System.out.println("2- -");
                System.out.println("3- *");
                System.out.println("4- /");
                System.out.println("5- =");

                op= sc.next().charAt(0);

                if (op!=1 && op!=2 && op!=3 && op!=4 && op!=5) {
                    System.out.println("Zadali ste nesprávne číslo");
                    return;
                }

                if (op==5) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Zadajte číslo");

            b= sc.nextDouble();

            if (i<1) {
                switch (op) {
                    case 1:
                        priklad = a + b;
                    case 2:
                        priklad = a - b;
                    case 3:
                        priklad = a * b;
                    case 4:
                        priklad = a / b;
                }
            }

            else {
                switch (op) {
                    case 1:
                        priklad = priklad + b;
                    case 2:
                        priklad = priklad - b;
                    case 3:
                        priklad = priklad * b;
                    case 4:
                        priklad = priklad / b;
                }
            }
            i=i++;
        }

        System.out.println("Výsledok je: "+priklad);
    }
}```
````

Comment: Note: `case` in Java need a `break` or a `return` at the end, otherwise code continues on next `case` - check [The switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A character is nothing but a number. That´s why you can compare a `char` with `int` as in your `op != 1`-check. However the appropriate number - the so-called ASCII-code - for `'1'` is not `1`, but `49`. `49` is surely not equal to `1`, so your condition `op != 1` matches.

Either check for `op == 49` or just `op == '1'` (for the further checks you surely need the appropriate ASCII-codes 50, 51 and 52).

Comment: tysm i will certainly learn more ASCII-code, but there´s one last thing i need to have it working. In the first switch, the first three cases are not working because the var ```priklad``` is grey and says "The value a+b (or a-b or a*b) assigned to ´priklad´ is never user". Could you help me with that too?

Comment: oh ok i´ve fixed it :)

Comment: These aren't really ASCII values, they're Unicode code points, it's just that the first 128 Unicode code points are identical to ASCII. Pedantic, I know, but it's a pet peeve of mine to refer to them as ASCII values when not using the ASCII character set.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is

```
                op = sc.next().charAt(0);

            if (op != 1 && op != 2 && op != 3 && op != 4) {
                System.out.println("Zadali ste nesprávne číslo");
                return;
            }
```

Op is a char, so when you get the input from the user it's '1', '2', '3', '4' but you check equality with 1, 2, 3, 4. Condition is always true and the program returns.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is, that when I input e.g. 1 at op = sc.next().charAt(0);,
>   the first if statement does its body, even if it's not true.

Replace

```
if (op != 1 && op != 2 && op != 3 && op != 4)
```

with

```
if (op != '1' && op != '2' && op != '3' && op != '4')
```

as you are comparing `char` values. If you want to compare with their ASCII values, you can use `op != 49` and so on. Check https://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap4/subsection2.1.1.1.html

The same applies to your `switch...case` also i.e. you should use `case '1'` instead of `case 1`.

> Also, it doesn't return at the start of the loop, but the program
>   ends.

Replace `return` with `continue`.